# Z-index doesn't work with overlapping a parent DIV with one inside it

Tags: html, css, z-index, jscrollbar

What I am trying to do is to hide the scrollbar of a DIV. In order to do that, I created an outer DIV with `overflow-y: hidden;` and placed a slightly wider DIV inside it.
I gave the outer DIV higher `z-index` than the inner one.
Both have `position: fixed;`, but no matter what, it doesn't work – the wider DIV is still visible outside its parent DIV.
I also made it so that `z-index` of `html` would be higher than that of the inner DIV, in hopes it would hide the scrollbar, but that didn't work either. Neither did using negative `z-index` work.
I've searched for days for a fix to this but none worked.

Here is the basic example code(should I include the entire code in *jsfiddle*?) - HTML:

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="#BFBFBF">
       <div class="outer_MB">
          <div class="in_MB">
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    z-index: 2;
}

.outer_MB {
    position: fixed;
    height: 70%;
    width: 84%;
    left: 8%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.in_MB {
    height: 70%;
    width: 86%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

*PM: This is the first question I asked on this website, so tell me if I'm missing something and I'll try to fix it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `.in_MB` element is tied to the `outer_MB` element. No matter what your inner element's `z-index` is set to, it will always display on top of the outer element.

Imagine having two boxes. A large box and a small box. You place the small box inside the large box. You then lift the large box up - the small box doesn't stay where it is, it lifts with the large box.

If you want `.in_MB` to appear behind `.outer_MB`, you'll need to make them separate elements:

```
<div class="outer_MB"></div>
<div class="in_MB"></div>
```

You'll then need to style the `.in_MB` element to appear in the same position as the `.outer_MB` element. As these elements are now separate but share the same overall ancestor, the `z-index` will kick into action accordingly.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't thought of that!
Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1):

So the gist of you problem is you need a div which **allows scrolling** but the **scrollbar should not be visible**...

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QzmH/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 99%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The problem with this approach is that different browsers have different sized scrollbars. In Chrome on Windows I can see a feint line where the scrollbar is still partly visible, because in the browser I'm using the scrollbar is 17px wide - larger than the 15px you've defined. Furthermore some browsers will have a much thinner scrollbar or worse, scrollbars which appear on top of content (tablets, etc.), so this solution may cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Thanks @JamesDonnelly!! I can see the problem now. I tested on 3 browsers and firefox shows a thin scrollbar moving.. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: I figured that already. The thing is, my DIV is only about ~84% wide. I used a similar way, but the inner DIV was still visible inside the body. That method is to hide the scrollbar of the entire page, not a small DIV.
Or that's how I see it, at least.
It is possible to make my inner DIV wider and have an enormous amount of padding, but that would be a little too hacky.